# Typo3 Introduction Package version 9.5

Tags: php, installation, typo3, version

Im trying to install the installation package from Typo3 with Composer but not the latest version. I need 9.5.
Do you know how can i do it with composer ?
installing the extension installs only the latest version. In the Webpage there´s a zip file but i dont know if i can use it with composer..

Thank you!

Comment: What **exactly** have you tried? There should be tons of tutorials out in the wild that tell you how to install a specific package version through composer

Answer (score 2):

Just add the version you want to install as parameter to composer:

```
composer create-project typo3/cms-base-distribution my-new-project 9.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following:

e.g. in your `composer.json`

```
"require": {
    "vendor/package": "1.3.2", // exactly 1.3.2
```

in your case:

```
 {
    "require": {
        "typo3/cms": "9.5"
    } 
}
```

For more info on versioning, have a look at [Composer - Version and Constraints](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md)

**EDIT:**
[Error](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.0/Breaking-83302-ComposerRestrictsInstallationOfTypo3cms.html): *When running a composer-based TYPO3 instance, it is not possible anymore to require the whole TYPO3 Core via composer require typo3/cms. This package is solely used for Core-development purposes from now on.*

Instead, all system extensions maintained by the TYPO3 Core Team must be required individually.

Some examples:

```
composer require typo3/cms-core:^9
composer require typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content:^9
composer require typo3/cms-extbase:^9
composer require typo3/cms-workspaces:^9
composer require typo3/cms-sys-note:^9
```

For convenience, TYPO3 projects can simply require composer require **typo3/minimal** to get the main system extensions that are needed for a running TYPO3 instance, and add custom system extensions as mentioned above.

Impact:
Installing or updating the composer package typo3/cms will show an error for TYPO3 v9.

i.e. use:

```
{
    "require": {
        "typo3/minimal": "9.5"
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer. Do i have to composer update? and its the composer.json from the introduction package or the one from my project?

Comment: Not sure what _the introduction package_ is, but normally your project would have a `composer.json` file that specifies all the required packages for your project. Use `composer install` to install the dependencies for your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following :

```
composer require typo3/cms-introduction:4.0.1
```

Introduction package version 4.0.1 is compatible with TYPO3 9.5, you can check : https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/introduction/